# Control Videos with javascript (e.g. streamcloud)

Tags: javascript, video

Is there a possibility to control videos from streamcloud, videoweed etc. via javascript?

One possibility that came to my mind was to use rapidleech and export the direct url to the video and then put the url into my -tag but I guess this is illegal, isnt it? I do not want to provide a download link just controls over the video.

Then someone give me a hint in the right direction maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the video in an iframe in your page.

Then you can emulate clicks on video with javascript.

You can see an example of this concept in youtube api from google [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)